# passing userloginid from controller to apicontroller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an mvc app where we follow custom authentication through an external package. After authentication, the username & otherdetails are sent through an object which can be accessed by 'Thread.CurrentPrincipal' property in the controller. I use the username from this object to log into my database for logging.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public string SyncProduct(string pIds)
    {
        var AuthenticatedUser = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as AuthenticatedUser;

        var model = new Model.Authentication.Authentication
        {
            User = AuthenticatedUser
        };

        string returnValue = null;
        try
        {
            returnValue = new SyncProduct().ProcessProducts(pIds);
            new Common().LogInfo(string.Format("ProcessIDS"), User.Identity.Name.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            new Common().LogException(string.Format("HomeController/SyncProduct", ex.ToString()), User.Identity.Name.ToString());
        }
        return string.Format("text:{0}", returnValue);
    }
}
```

I would like to log the same username in my api controller, but the User.Identity.Name.ToString() is null here. I wanted to know if there was a way I can pass just the value of User.Identity.Name.ToString() from homecontroller to apicontroller or make it global.

```
public class WebApiController : ApiController
{

    [HttpPut]
    public HttpResponseMessage Put(FormDataCollection form)
    {
        try
        {

        var AuthenticatedUser = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as AuthenticatedUser;

        var model = new Model.Authentication.Authentication
        {
            User = AuthenticatedUser
        };

        //code to update object
        new Common().LogInfo(string.Format("logging info", User.Identity.Name.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            new Common().LogException(string.Format("logging info", ex.ToString()), User.Identity.Name.ToString());
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspected that `WebApiController` doesn't have `[Authorize]` attribute or something like derived from it.

```
[Authorize]
public class WebApiController : ApiController
```

Comment: Thanks Rainman, but it is not beacuse of the [Authorize] attribute.